# iOS Auto Layout - Issue with constrains within Stack View

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have in my main view two elements.  A *Stack View* on the top of the frame, and a *View* at the bottom.  Inside the top *Stack View* I have some labels.  One of these two labels I want to have with a fixed distance to the parent container (The *Stack View*), while the other one I want to the edge.  As it is shown here:

[image]

I believe the constrains are visible correctly in this image.

Now, the constrain adding `50` units to the lead/trail of the label `Foo` do not work.  The error shown is the following:

[image]

For some reason, there is another extra constrain I have not added (The second one in the image) and that one, I cannot delete, but only the one I added (The `50` units).  If I apply this suggested change, it looks stretched to the lead/trail, as I want to avoid.

What am I doing wrong?  Why this is behaving in such an unpredictable way?  What is blocking my label to have a fixed lead/trail to its parent container, the *Stack View*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of these two labels I want to have with a fixed distance to the parent container (The Stack View), while the other one I want to the edge

Okay. So that would not be a stack view! Just put these labels into an *ordinary* view and configure the constraints.

The reason is that it is the job of a stack view to *make* constraints. It manufactures a bunch of constraints on the arranged subviews. Therefore *you* must not apply constraints to those arranged subviews; they will, as you have seen, conflict with what the stack view is doing.

What a stack view does is fixed, and limited. If you don't like what it does, don't use it. Remember, a stack view is not doing *anything* that you couldn't do yourself by writing the constraints yourself. So just do that.

Comment: I see.  So there is no way of setting constrains to leading/trailing if the parent stack view has a constrain for leading/trailing?  Is this the case?

Comment: What did I say in my answer? You cannot make constraints that position a stack view’s arranged subviews. The stack view makes those for you. That is what a stack view _is_.